# Wireshark: Byte order changes when data exported

Tags: wireshark

I am looking at a packet capture in Wireshark and try to export the data from a packet.

In Wireshark, it looks like this:

```
46 a5 e2 fb bd 69 ...
```

Then, after downloading, hexdump shows:

```
a5 46 fb e2 69 bd ...
```

The byte order has changed.

Why does this happen, and how can I simply export the data to a file as is? (I just used "Export selected packet bytes...").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP is [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), your x86 computer (or your hexdump's default) is little-endian.

---

Update:

Consider this

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt

$ hexdump foo.txt
0000000 6f66 0a6f
0000004

$ hexdump -C foo.txt
00000000  66 6f 6f 0a                                       |foo.|
00000004
```

Especially consider the position of the two `o`'s in `foo` and the position of the two `6f`'s in the output of the first `hexdump` above.

Comment: OK, so network byte order is always big endian, right? So am I guaranteed that the data I am looking at on my drive is in fact correct, i.e. I don't need to switch the byte order to view it properly? I thought it is gzip data but am unable to inflate it, so I thought that maybe if I switch the byte order I could. Thanks.

Comment: I am willing to accept this answer if it comes with a more detailed explanation, especially answer the question in my previous comment.

Comment: @mydoghasworms: See update. Where do I send the invoice?